# A parameter containing real numbers not accepted on Linux

Tags: command-line

Firstly, this command works on Windows command prompt well.

```
kdu_expand -i /home/tmp/1.jp2 -o /home/tmp/1.tif -region {0.1,0.1},{0.1,0.1}
```

In Linux, I get the following error:

```
The `-region' argument requires a set of coordinates of the form, "{<top>,<left>},{<height>,<width>}". All quantities must be real numbers in the range 0 to 1.
```

If I remove the `-region` parameter and run like this:

```
kdu_expand -i /home/tmp/1.jp2 -o /home/tmp/1.tif
```

it works on Linux too.

Here is the part of the code which parses the parameter:

```c++
    static void
  set_region_of_interest(kdu_args &args, kdu_dims &region, siz_params *siz,
                         double &width_fraction, double &height_fraction)
  /* Parses the `-region' argument to see if a reduced region of interest
     is required.  Returns the region of interest, expressed on the
     original codestream canvas (no geometric transformations) along with
     the fraction of the full image width and height which are represented
     by this region. */
{
  width_fraction = height_fraction = 1.0;
  if (!(siz->get(Sorigin,0,0,region.pos.y) &&
        siz->get(Sorigin,0,1,region.pos.x) &&
        siz->get(Ssize,0,0,region.size.y) &&
        siz->get(Ssize,0,1,region.size.x)))
    assert(0);
  region.size.y -= region.pos.y;
  region.size.x -= region.pos.x;
  if (args.find("-region") == NULL)
    return;
  char *string = args.advance();
  if (string != NULL)
    {
      double top, left, height, width;

      if (sscanf(string,"{%lf,%lf},{%lf,%lf}",&top,&left,&height,&width) != 4)
        string = NULL;
      else if ((top < 0.0) || (left < 0.0) || (height < 0.0) || (width < 0.0))
        string = NULL;
      else
        {
          region.pos.y += (int) floor(region.size.y * top);
          region.pos.x += (int) floor(region.size.x * left);
          region.size.y = (int) ceil(region.size.y * height);
          region.size.x = (int) ceil(region.size.x * width);
          width_fraction = width;
          height_fraction = height;
        }
    }
  if (string == NULL)
    { kdu_error e; e << "The `-region' argument requires a set of coordinates "
      "of the form, \"{<top>,<left>},{<height>,<width>}\". All quantities "
      "must be real numbers in the range 0 to 1."; }
  args.advance();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `{0.1,0.1},{0.1,0.1}` is subject to the [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) in Linux shell. You can check it with `echo`:

```
$ echo {0.1,0.1},{0.1,0.1}
0.1,0.1 0.1,0.1 0.1,0.1 0.1,0.1

$ echo A{0.1,0.1},{0.1,0.1}B
A0.1,0.1B A0.1,0.1B A0.1,0.1B A0.1,0.1B
```

To prevent this behavior, enclose the parameter into single quotes (`'...'`).

```
kdu_expand -i /home/tmp/1.jp2 -o /home/tmp/1.tif -region '{0.1,0.1},{0.1,0.1}'
```